# Upload multiple files without having to select every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

With HTML5 and ASP.NET 4.5, I created a page that will allow the user to upload multiple files. The ASPX code looks like:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true"  />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />`
```

c# code:

```
    protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
            {                  
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                uploadedFile.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Uploaded\\" + fileName);
                listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

The user selects the files using the FileUpload control and clicks the Upload button and it works great.

My question is: Is is possible to upload files using this method without the user selecting the files? I'd like to have the app always point to a directory on the users hard drive and default to uploading the files in that directory. 
The user would see the contents of that directory in a list box and click the upload button or some variation to that. 
I don't see any way to add files to the FileUpload control in code.

Comment: The browser does not support that.

Comment: What you describe is considered a security risk and therefore modern browsers do not support it.

Comment: Is this a public website, or is it an internal business application where you can expect all users to be on the company's network?

Comment: It's a public web site. Users have an account they log into to access it.